# How to centralize bars in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-science

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

h=[p1,p2,p3,p4]
r=['page 1','page 2','page 3','page 4']
h
plt.barh(r, h, align ='edge')
```

I want to make a symmetrical diagram. How can I do it?

Comment: What are `p1,p2,p3,p4`? Would be helpful to have a [reprex]

Comment: p1, ..., p4 - numbers.

Comment: I want them to be in the center, not on the left side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtracting each of the widths from the maximum and dividing by two to set the left starting point of the bars would result in centered bars. Numpy helps in writing the expressions concisely.

Bar standard use "sticky" edges. Vertical bars stand firmly on the `y=0` base instead of hovering in the air. Horizontal bars standard stick to an `x=0` base.
Setting `use_sticky_edges` of the plot's `ax` to False removes that default, and helps to give a symmetric aspect.

Optionally, the labels can also be centered.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

h = [12, 22, 19, 5]
r = ['page 1', 'page 2', 'page 3', 'page 4']
h = np.array(h)
plt.gca().use_sticky_edges = False
plt.barh(r, width=h, left=(h.max() - h) / 2, align='center', color='crimson')
for ri in r:
    plt.text(h.max() / 2, ri, ri, ha='center', va='center', color='white', size=16)
plt.yticks([]) # optionally remove standard y ticks and their labels
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

PS: An idea to put `x=0` in the center is to double the width and let the bars start at `-h`:

```py
plt.barh(r, width=h*2, left=-h, align='center', color='crimson')
for ri in r:
    plt.text(x=0, y=ri, s=ri, ha='center', va='center', color='white', size=16)
```

Comment: But how to put the zero of coordinates into the center too?

Comment: What means parameter 'ri' here ? If I change the values the text goes beyond blocks.

Comment: I edited the answer with a possible approach. Instead of doubling `plt.barh(r, width=h, left=-h/2)` is another possibility.

Comment: I mean exactly the arguments of plt.text. Cannot understand how it works

Comment: `ri` goes to through the values of `r` one by one. So, `ri` would be the i'th entry of `r`. It is used both for the y-position and for the text to put on the plot.

Comment: If I change the values, all the structure breaks, so what is it up to?

Comment: Could you edit your question and put an example of something that doesn't work?